# Why does Air act as a conductor in presence of a Strong Electric Field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, field-theory

We know that Air is a good insulator but why does it become conducting in presence of a strong electric field?.

Comment: Did you search for [Electrical breakdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_breakdown) on wikipedia?

Answer (score 4):

In the presence of a strong electric field, electrons will be stripped off molecules in the air creating a plasma of ions and electrons. The charged particles in the plasma can carry a current as long as the power being pumped into the plasma is enough to prevent the electrons and ions from re-combining.

Answer (score 0):

Air acts as an insulator in normal conditions because it is majorly composed of stable gases like oxygen and nitrogen. As we know both oxygen and nitrogen are highly electronegative elements and it is difficult to remove electrons from them. (This is without even considering the highly stable bonds of oxygen and nitrogen molecules.)
Therefore a strong electric field is required to extract these electrons from the air molecules which then conduct electricity.